# Is there a way to force focus on a selectable on android TV when hasTVPreferredFocus is ignored?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, android-tv

The documentation suggests that `hasTVPreferredFocus` is only for tvOS, but other questions/answers suggest that it works for android as well. It seems to be working in some cases for me (e.g. when a screen initially loads), but in other cases it does not. In this case, I have a grid of selectable elements. When clicked, the item's index is stored and the `hasTVPreferredFocus` property is set to `true` on that item for the next time it renders. A new screen is pushed to the stack, and a button on the left side of the new screen is focused. When popping the stack, I want the originally selected item to regain focus, but the property is ignored, and a different element is automatically selected, specifically and consistently the first element in the row that was previously selected. It appears that the engine is trying to find the next closest item to the popped screen's last focused item, which happened to be on the left side of the screen, and ignores the `hasTVPreferredFocus` property. Since this property is not working as expected, is there any way to achieve this, by manually forcing/setting the focus to the correct element?

One of my attempts was to listen with the `useFocusEffect` event, which would temporarily disable the onBlur and onFocus events of the grid items, which visually made it look like the item I wanted was still selected, but internally the first item in the row still had focus, without the visual indicator. After moving the cursor, the visual indicator of the real selection appeared as expected (relative to the first item in the row, not the clicked item), while the originally clicked item was left with a "phantom" selection until the cursor moved back onto it.

- Example of issue: https://i.imgur.com/k0LJNhH.mp4
- My (failed) attempt: https://i.imgur.com/4epnkwO.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you want todo if your using react-native-navigation is to grab the navigation onfocus event and then set focus in the on focus of navigation that or if your using a flatlist or flatlist grid view you should be able to use scroll to index or select that index if your saving it had the same issue my self